# Multiple class files in java file and testng.xml

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng, testng-eclipse

I have two class files in the same java file. How do I call them both in the `testng.xml` classes list? For e.g I have two classes A and B and the java file name is obviously `A.java` with A as a class. How do I call the class B from `testng.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You would basically use the `$` symbol to refer to inner classes.

Assuming you have a sample such as the one shown below

```java
package com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn53476365;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleClass {

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
    System.err.println("Hello from SampleClass");
  }

  public static class InnerClass {

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
      System.err.println("Hello from InnerClass");
    }
  }
}
```

You would refer to the `InnerClass` as shown below in your `testng.xml` file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="53476365_Suite" parallel="false" verbose="2">
    <test name="53476365_Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn53476365.SampleClass"/>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn53476365.SampleClass$InnerClass"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Output is as below

```
...
... TestNG 7.0.0-beta1 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...
Hello from SampleClass

Hello from InnerClass
PASSED: testMethod
PASSED: testMethod

===============================================
    53476365_Test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

===============================================
53476365_Suite
Total tests run: 2, Passes: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```